# How do I read the 2[W] and 'at level X' of attack cards?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Probably a simple question but one I cannot figure out from the books:

Some power and attack cards have at the HIT statement a small symbol saying 1[W], or 2[W] at level 21. For example:

[image: cleave's power card]

How do I read the 2[W]? Is it 2 times the weapon? does someone need to roll 2 d20 checks? I understand this is probably for the higher levels but my players ask questions alot and I just want to be prepared. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is nothing special for *power cards* in particular - powers in the books share this notation as well.

The [W] means your weapon damage dice. Crack your Player's Handbook open to page 276 — the *Attack Results* section — and look at the right hand side.

As in the example it gives: if the weapon you're using for this power is a regular dagger, your damage dice is 1d4. If a power instructs you to roll 2[W], you roll twice that. For a dagger, that means 2d4.

If your weapon dice consists of multiple dice already, you still roll twice that for 2[W]. A Scythe's weapon damage dice is 2d4, so 1[W] means 2d4, 2[W] means 4d4, 3[W] means 6d4, etc.

If you're still getting used to the combat system and powers (i.e. most things you will use often), there's a few sections you should liberally refer to:

- The *Combat* chapter, on PHB page 264.
- The *How to read a power* section, which is located right near the beginning of the *Classes* chapter (since that's where all the powers are) and begins at page 54.
- Also, equipment blocks (or equipment cards) aren't *quite* the same as power blocks (and cards). They're explained in the *Equipment* chapter, right at the beginning of the *Magic items* section, under the heading *Reading a Magic Item* on page 224.

**The "at level 21" bit** means your power upgrades at level 21. A lot of at-wills do this (and so do some other powers), because they'll be with you the whole way and had better not get outdated. From levels 1 to 20, you'll be rolling 1[W] for damage, but as of level 21, you'll roll 2[W] instead. (That's the "increase damage to" bit.)

Answer (score 4):

2[W] means roll whichever dice of damage your weapon uses twice if you hit

a longsword would be 2d8, a dagger 2d4, or a greataxe 2d12

likewise 3[W] is 3 dice

a weapon's [W] can be multiple dice, especially for oversized 2 handers, and 2[W] of a 2d4 weapon would be 4d4

Comment: -1, What about 'at level X'?

Comment: Why downvote this answer rather than upvote Jonathan's?

Comment: I came across [this meta question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently), and I think it answers your question better than my previous comment.